# RuntimeError - No input found for binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

So I have a Ruby on Rails setup with Devise and Paperclip. I managed to convert my erb files to HAML and still having issues when I try to put an attachment input on the New registration view. I took the proper steps to do the migration with Paperclip, The User table has all the proper image columns but still getting a runtime error when I put the image input on the page.

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails (only about a month of learning and doing some screencasts and courses) and I'm really stuck. I would rather not do this all over again, as it took some time to build but I was hoping to get some answers here! thanks!

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "haml"
```

Here is the error:

```
Extracted source (around line #6):

3:   = f.error_notification
4:   = f.full_error :image_file_size, class: "alert alert-error"
5:   = f.full_error :image_content_type, class: "alert alert-error"
6:   = f.input :image, label: "Upload an image"
7:   = f.input :name, :autofocus => true
8:   = f.input :email
9:   = f.input :password

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.haml:6:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_haml___1664083891059168154_70305669109760'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_haml___1664083891059168154_70305669109760'
```

This is the new.html.haml view:

```
%h2 Sign up
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
= f.error_notification
= f.full_error :image_file_size, class: "alert alert-error"
= f.full_error :image_content_type, class: "alert alert-error"
= f.input :image, label: "Upload an image"
= f.input :name, :autofocus => true
= f.input :email
= f.input :password
= f.input :password_confirmation
.form-actions
    = f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary"
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

Here is the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid, :image
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
        content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] }, size: { less_than: 2.megabytes }
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}
end
```

Oh and here is my DB schema:

```
add_index "referrals", ["user_id"], :name => "index_referrals_on_user_id"

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",                        :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                             :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.binary   "image",                  :limit => 1048576
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end

    add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
    add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true
```

Oh one last thing, I did install ImageMagick on my OSX machine (10.8) before installing paperclip

Comment: please try `= f.input :image, as: :file, label: "Upload an image"`

Comment: Thank you Nash! I thought I actually used as: :file attribute but I guess I missed that part. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste whole error? What's the error title? The code & error you've shown is just line in which it happend, though we still don't know what exactly it throws.

PS. About the view - hope it's just wrong paste, because as I can see, it has wrongly intended blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up fixing the page error

```
= f.input :image, as: :file, label: "Upload an image"
```